# Bubble Sort errors with more than 3 entries in array (ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, bubble-sort

I  ran into an issue with my bubble sort. It seemed like it was really close to working  as it will sort correctly up to three numbers. When I add a fourth it returns:

```
in `>': comparison of Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError)
```

I tried going through it in debug mode but I'm not sure where the problem is. The lessons I'm using haven't covered recursion yet so I'm assuming I'm supposed to be able to solve this without it.

```
def bubble(array)
  x=0
  while array!=array.sort
      if array[x]>array[x+1]
          nu=array.slice(x)
          array.delete_at(x)
          array<<nu
      else
        x+=1
      end
    end
  puts "Sorted array: #{array}"
end
```

`slice` wasn't deleting the entry so I added `delete_at`.

Comment: Why are you sorting the array n² times? Also, note that neither `Enumerable#sort` nor your bubble sort are stable, so it is possibly that your loop condition will never false.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did't check the array boundary, you should check the array boundary may like

```
n = array.length

# while loop  
# ... 
# a loop with array boundary
  (n-1).times do |x|
      # swap element in here
  end
#end while loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!